# RSA encryption confidentiality

Tags: rsa

In this scheme , is confidentiality guaranteed? A sends to B an encrypted file which is encrypted by B's public key.
Can you illustrate any variant, still RSA- based but also using symmetric cryptography (no pre-shared keys) and lowering CPU time?

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: No, i found it on previous exam questions . I' m trying to do some past exams and i didn't know how to answer.

Comment: The whole point of the exercise isn't for someone else to do it for you, you know: if you do not know the answer or do not understand the question, it means you need to go back to your learning material and study it again.

Comment: Yes for sure, i'm doing so just wanted to have some ideas . As the topic we did in class about rsa was not a profound study i had no idea how to deal with a question like this at the exam .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption is about maintaining confidentiality so I daresay that if you encrypt then you maintain confidentiality.

The exam question you quote probably wants you to talk about [hybrid encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) (use RSA to encrypt an AES key; use AES to encrypt gigabytes of data). Look it up !